# I don't get this message: "If you have Linux installed, please reinit its boot loader"

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-8

I just used Paragon Partition Manager Free Edition 2014 on my Windows 8 to transfer space from one of my Windows logical partition to my Ubuntu Linux partition (I have only one partition for Ubuntu). After the operation, the software gave me a message: "If you have Linux installed, please reinit its boot loader". I do not know how I am supposed to reinit its boot loader or what exactly a boot loader is (besides Grub). So, what do I do before I reboot my computer. I am not fond of broken loading screens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "If you have Linux installed, please reinit its boot loader"

It asks you to reinstall grub2 bootloader on your hard-disk.To do that, simply run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3a_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu).

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a usb or CD? I do not have either with me at the moment: I only have a 1GB flash drive.

Comment: 1 gb flash drive is enough.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the LIVE CD Rescatux utility, and then click on the "Restore Grub" option, then select the Linux distribution to repair and go.